# Components of a Continuous Random Variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Given a discrete random variable (say uniformly distributed) $X$ on $\lbrace 1,2,\ldots,n\rbrace$, there are some natural ways to define "components" of $X$, such as the following:

(i) If we consider prime factorization, $X=\prod_{p\le n,\, p \text{ prime}}p^{X_p}$, the distribution of $X$ determines a component process $(X_p)$ of the prime powers of $X$.

(ii) If we consider the integer partition of $X$: $X=\sum_{i\le n} Y_i$, with $Y_i\le Y_{i+1}$, the distribution of $X$ determines the distribution of a  component process $(Y_i)$.

Question: If $X$ is a continuous random variable on $(0,n)$ is there any analogous way to define continuous-time "components" of $X$? The correspondence need not be in the form of an equation such as in (i) or (ii) above, but the $(X_i)$ should be dependent and (not necessarily uniquely) determined by $X$.

**Update**: The only example that I have is $X_i=1_{\lbrace N\ge i\rbrace}$ (each $X_i$ is discrete, but $i$ takes on any real number in $(0,n)$).

Comment: You could have something similar to your second case, $X=\int_0^T Y(t) dt$ with $Y(t)$ almost surely increasing. Not sure how this is useful though (more generally talking about the two decomposition you are mentioning), could you say how these can be used ?

Comment: @P.Quinton My work is motivated by the coupling results in (https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.0941). In case (i) of the OP, the prime powers $X_p$ converge in distribution to an independent process $(Z_p)$ of geometric RVs. This motivates the author to construct a coupling of $X$ with another variable $Y$ (who components are given by $Z_p$).